# Django Serialization Returns an empty list

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Hello Guy I'm a newbie to Django. Im using Rest API with Django to interact with my android application. **I have the data I need in variable quest**. Since there are multiple questions I'm using filter instead of get.

This is my Views.py:

```
class MapertablesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Mapertables.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MapertablesSerializer
    lookup_field = 'category_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        #print self.kwargs['category_id']
        maps = Mapertables.objects.filter(category_id=self.kwargs['category_id'])
        #queryset = list(maps)
        #queryset =  serializers.serialize('json',maps)
        #print "AAAA ",queryset
        i = 0
        #quest ={}
        queryset = []
        queslist = []
        for question in maps:
            quest = {}
            quest['question'] = question.question_id
            #print 'qqqq  ',question.question_id
            #queryset =  serializers.serialize('json',[question,])
            choices = Choice.objects.filter(question=question.question_id)
            print choices
            #aaa = chain(question,choices)
            #print aaa
            #queryset =  serializers.serialize('json',[question,choices,])
            j = 0
            for option in choices:
                quest[j] = option.choice_text
                j += 1
            print 'data Here ',quest
            #data Here  {0: u'Highbury', 1: u'Selhurst Park', 2: u'The Dell', 3: u'Old Trafford', 'question': <Question: At which ground did Eric Cantona commit his "Kung Fu" kick ?>}
            serializer_class = CoustomeSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            print serializer_class.data
            #[]
            json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer_class.data)
            print 'JSON',json
            #[]
            i += 1

        queryset = queslist
        serializer_class = CoustomeSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return queryset
        #print "questions",queslist
        #print "Ser ",ser.data
```

This is my serializers.py:

```
class  MapertablesSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =  Mapertables
        fields = ('question_id','category_id')


class CoustomeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    #questions =  MapertablesSerializer(source='question_id')
    #choices = ChoiceSerializer(source='choice_text')
    class Meta:
        model = Question,Choice,Category
        fields = ('choice_text','choice_text','choice_text','choice_text','question_id')
```

URL that is defined to show:
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/mapers/
    Exception Type: KeyError
    Exception Value: 'category_id'

when I query for a specific category it returns:
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/mapers/2/
    {
       "detail": "Not found."
    }

Model.py file is as follows:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='1')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #category_name = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Mapertables(models.Model):
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

I want to get all questions related to category and there choices form the choices module that why all the stuff in get_queryset.

Please tell me how to get all the data required for me in  MapertablesViewSet class

Thank You in advance if you want me to send the complete project just let me know and I will make zip and upload it to a drive or something.

Comment: you See the output of quest and serializer_class  thats where the code is breaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kevin Brown is right you shouldn't worry about the serializers, or rendering anything on the `get_queryset` method, but a thing I noticed in your `get_queryset` method is that you don't append any item to the lists `queryset`, and `querylist`. I'm giving you an idea below:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        #print self.kwargs['category_id']
        maps = Mapertables.objects.filter(category_id=self.kwargs['category_id'])
        i = 0
        queryset = []
        for question in maps:
            quest = {}
            quest['question'] = question.question_id
            choices = Choice.objects.filter(question=question.question_id)
            print choices

            j = 0
            for option in choices:
                quest[j] = option.choice_text
                j += 1
            print 'data Here ',quest
            # Adding items to queryset list
            queryset.append(quest)
            i += 1

        # You should have values here on queryset list
        print queryset

        return queryset
```

As to the URL, be sure you are passing the `category_id` as a parameter on the URL pattern. Something like `url(r'^mapers/(?P<category_id>\d+)/?'`, if you are not using `routers` for this. It would be good if you paste here your URLs definition. Well, I hope it helps you to have a better idea how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an empty list from your `get_queryset` method, so no objects are being returned in the list view and a specific object cannot be retrieved by the `pk`.

You appear to be doing a lot of unrelated things in your `get_queryset` method, and they are probably contributing to this issue. You shouldn't be doing any serialization there, DRF will handle that for you later. And you should be doing filtering in the `filter_queryset` method, or passing that off to DRF to do. You also can't return any responses from that method, only a queryset.

Comment: thank you for your time. The things in get_queryset is to get all the database on category . I takeing the category id and retrieving the questions .The Getting Choices for the Question.     Is there a easy way to do it . if so please suggest . Really Thanks you .. And i will also look into filter_queryset